# How do I change slider size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, label

I'm new here. I'm trying to increase the size of these numbers here in the slider but I can't manage to to that.

[image: Image with colorbar and sliders]

I would like these numbers to be of size 22, as the other labels in the image.
Thank you all in advance.